# Swift DispatchGroup causes error: [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase & Firestore to read in data using:

```
var itemData: [String:Any]?
let docRef = db.collection("store").document(documentID)

let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            print("Document data: \(document.data() ?? ["key":"__data__"])")
            itemData = document.data()
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
        group.leave()
    }
}
group.wait()
print("ITEM_DATA: \(itemData)")
return itemData
```

when I remove all references of any DispatchGroup, group.enter(), etc... the code runs okay, albeit not in the order that I want it to (i.e. it runs the `print("ITEM_DATA: \(itemData)")` line with itemData as nil and only later prints out the result of `print("Document data: \(document.data() ?? ["key":"__data__"])")`). So I know that there isn't anything wrong with the actual request to Firebase.

However, when I try to fix the issue of into printing/returning `itemData` before I write to it, with the DispatchGroup as in the code above, when I run the function, the program gives me the error code:

```
[Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10.000000 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

The program never connects to Firestore after I get this message. I've tried this with simulators and actual devices both with and without wifi, but to no avail. I know it's not a problem with my internet connection because it works when I remove all the stuff with DispatchGroup, but I still can't figure out what the issue is or how to get around this problem.

Comment: Don't misuse `DispatchGroup` to force asynchronous tasks to become synchronous. Learn to understand how asynchronous data processing works and implement a completion handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try entering and leaving the Dispatch Group being in a same `Queue`

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    group.enter()
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            print("Document data: \(document.data() ?? ["key":"__data__"])")
            itemData = document.data()
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
        group.leave()
    }
}
group.wait()
print("ITEM_DATA: \(itemData)")
```

**In case you are wondering what have I changed in your method?**

Take a look at enter statement moving inside `DispatchQueue` async closure

**What might be causing the issue?**

Entering a Dispatch Group being in different queue and leaving dispatch group while being in a different queue might be causing the issue

**EDIT 1:**

Hey, just tested your code and got it to work

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        group.enter()
        sleep(10)
        debugPrint("Hello")
        group.leave()
    }
    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        print("ITEM_DATA: )")
    }
```

Here is the out put sequence from console

1. "Hello"
2. ITEM_DATA: )

I know I am not using `wait()` and `wait()` should also work but little busy with my work so can't test with wait right now

**EDIT 2:**

Just realised that OP is intending to return a value from a async function using `Dispatch group` hence updating my answer for the same

You can't have a return statement from a async call no matter what logic you apply. Dispatch group will not help you here, all that you need here is a `closure` or `block`

```
func test(onCompletion completion: @escaping ([String:Any]) -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                completion(document.data())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And call it as

```
    self.test {[weak self] (data) in
        debugPrint(data)
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This somewhat solved my problem: I am no longer getting the error, but the program is still not executing in the order I want it to. It is still executing `print("ITEM_DATA: \(itemData)")` before executing `print("Document data: \(document.data() ?? ["key":"__data__"])")`. Shouldn't the `group.wait()` statement prevent the program from moving on?

Comment: @jeffrey-chen: Gimme sometime Ill check n get back

Comment: thanks! This almost works, but I still need to return itemData after printing it, which I cannot do from within the call to group.notify.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! But I am still curious as to why group.wait() would not work

Comment: @jeffrey-chen : for the obvious reason that you have to enter and leave dispatch group in same Queue. So your group enter leave and wait will be inside your dispatch async that will never block return statement declared outside. So if you decide to move return statement inside the block that won't work either because blocks can never return anything. Blocks are executed asynchronously where as functions are executed synchronously so a synchronous function can't have any return value from a async block :) Think about it, it will make sense logically as well :)